# $ionic.Platform.ready not firing in android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I currently have the $ionicPlatform event listener in my app.js. I know it's working in the test environment on the pc browser, but when I build the app and run it on my android device, the ionicPlatform.ready never actually runs/fires. Any ideas?

Here are some threads/questions posted, with some solutions that haven't worked for me.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1751

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421291/code-inside-ionic-platform-ready-not-getting-fired-up

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('who', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $cordovaDevice) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    var push = new Ionic.Push({
      "debug": true
    });
    push.register(function(token) {
      console.log("Device token:",token.token);
    });
    console.log('reached end of ionic platform ready');
  });
})
```

UPDATE 12/14/2015 @ 5:24 AM - I have a view/activity that loads first, it renders the results from the $ionic.platform.ready listener. Upon loading the app, it renders nothing. What's interesting is this, after going to another view/activity, and then going back to the first view/activity, the result is then loaded/rendered. Any ideas?

UPDATE 12/14/2015 @ 5:30 AM - I have tried ionic.Platform.ready, I have tried  the document.addEventlistener 'deviceready'. None of them are working, and $ionicPlatform.ready gives me the least amount of problems, so I have defaulted to that.

Comment: I have a view/activity that loads first, it renders the results from the $ionic.platform.ready listener. Upon loading the app, it renders nothing. What's interesting is this, after going to another view/activity, and then going back to the first view/activity, the result is then loaded/rendered. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try ionic.Platform.ready(funtion(){}) instead?

Comment: @Muhsin Yes, I have tried ionic.Platform.ready, I have tried  the document.addEventlistener 'deviceready'. None of them are working, and $ionicPlatform.ready gives me the least amount of problems, so I have defaulted to that.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to go with this workaround for now, unless someone can refactor this better for me.

The data retrieved in the $ionicPlatform.ready would not be rendered in the first activity loaded. I would usually have to navigate to at least 1 more activity and then go back to see the results. Now I know ionicFramework has it's own default splash activity that I don't want to override for this purpose (for now), so I added another view/state/activity that just serves as a buffer and immediately navigates to the results activity.

1. app loaded <- the ionic platform ready should be fired here, but it doesn't
2. ionic splash activity
3. buffer activity
4. result activity <- ionic platform ready finally fires up, weird.

Could just be my misunderstanding of Ionic's data synchronization, but this dirty fix seems to have solved it.